# Is there a version of str_detect to find duplicates?

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a dataset with multiple columns containing identifiers and I need to identify duplicates based on the identifiers. I created a new column with all the identifier columns pasted together, but I'm not sure how to actually detect the duplicates.

The current dataset looks like this:

```
id <- (1:10)
record <- c("A | B", "A", "--C--", "B", "CD", "D", "ABCD", "B | D | A", "C", "data:D")
df <- data.frame(id, record)
```

```
   id      record
   1        A | B
   2            A
   3        --C--
   4            B
   5           CD
   6            D
   7         ABCD
   8    B | D | A
   9            C
 10        data:D
```

I want to find duplicate rows based on A, B, C and D. For example it should tell me that 5, 6, 7, 8, and 10 have matches because they all contain D.

I prefer a `tidyverse` solution and have been playing around with `stringr` and `dplyr` with no luck. I don't want to search for a specific pattern but rather find all rows that contain the same strings as each other.

Comment: can you be more specific? why do you mention duplicate records when you only seem to be searching for substrings `grep('D', df$record)`

Comment: I put together a dataset from a bunch of sources, and the sources kept their identifiers spread across different columns, with most records have multiple identifiers. So the dataset is too large and complex to look for specific instances like "D"

Answer (score 1):

```r
id <- (1:10)
record <- c("A | B", "A", "--C--", "B", "CD", "D", "ABCD", "B | D | A", "C", "data:D")
df <- data.frame(id, record)

df$index <- stringr::str_extract_all(df$record, "[A-Z]")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

res = unnest(df) %>% tidyr::spread(index,-id)

> res
# A tibble: 10 x 6
      id record    A     B     C     D    
   <int> <fct>     <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1     1 A | B     A     B     NA    NA   
 2     2 A         A     NA    NA    NA   
 3     3 --C--     NA    NA    C     NA   
 4     4 B         NA    B     NA    NA   
 5     5 CD        NA    NA    C     D    
 6     6 D         NA    NA    NA    D    
 7     7 ABCD      A     B     C     D    
 8     8 B | D | A A     B     NA    D    
 9     9 C         NA    NA    C     NA   
10    10 data:D    NA    NA    NA    D
```

Comment: In the actual dataframe the record column is a combination of character, numeric, and character + numeric identifiers, not just the letters as I put in the example. Is there a way to detect those with str_extract_all? If for example I wanted to detect the data:D value for record?

Comment: You could use an or logical operator `df$index <- stringr::str_extract_all(df$record, "(?:[A-Z]|data:D)")`

Comment: I don't know the actual strings I'm looking for, I just want to see duplicates

Comment: So you might be interested  by stringsim in stringdist package. Might be valuable if you create a new issue with a more precise information. Try to reproduce your dateset more closely.

Comment: My dataset is very large and the lists of identifiers are very long, so I'm afraid any reproducible example I can create would not be much better than what I have provided. Thank you for your suggestion, I am looking into the stringdist package